# Is questioning how a soon-to-be-added feature is going to work Developer Intent?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

So I just asked a question about the effects a new mechanic will have on gameplay. The update has been announced and released on public beta, but not implemented into the game itself. I quickly deleted it after someone pointed out that it is not on topic for this site. Is this "developer intent" and therefore off topic?

In which case, where should I go to ask about this? It's not a question to ask the Game Dev SE and I can't find any other SE sites relating to Developer Intent. There might be an Area 51 proposal, but it seems like such a small topic it will never become a site.

Comment: When in doubt you could always try taking this topic to Reddit if you're dead-set on talking to someone about it.

Comment: Unreleased functionality isn't something we'd be able to answer definitively - if the function is in a closed or open beta we might be able to share some insights but if it's only just been announced and not implemented we can't tell you any more than the devs have already said.

Answer (score 8):

A question about an unreleased feature would not be off-topic for developer intent, but it would be off-topic for being about unreleased content.

If your question was asking about a feature that is currently in public beta, **then it is 100% on-topic** (though things like this have been quickly closed and then reopened in the past, like [whenever a new Overwatch hero is made playable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/is-sombra-fully-invisible-when-using-her-thermoptic-camo)).

From the closure reasons:

> Questions about unreleased or illegal content are off topic on Arqade. We only support questions about games available to the general public through legitimate means.

The reason these questions are off-topic is because without the ability to actually access content, our answers are educated guesses, at best. If content is available to the public, then there's nothing wrong with the question on that end.

Answer (score 1):

Developer intent questions are off-topic because they are unanswerable except by the developers themselves. Usually, questions of this nature take the form of "why was X designed this way?" or "when will X be available?". Even though these questions are sometimes answerable by the general public (for example, by linking to a video interview where the devs answer the question being asked), it just opens a can of worms that we'd rather just avoid. Questions like this also include queries about future games - since none of us can play the game, we can't verify any answer as correct other than to trust whatever the devs might have said.

Once the game (or the game mechanic, in this case) is released and is potentially playable by user of this site, the question is no longer about unreleased content and it is okay to ask. For example, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/305134/what-is-the-limit-of-lovers-leap/305136) was asked very shortly after two new characters were released on the game's public testing server - not in the official game, but still playable while being tweaked. This question was and still is valid.